# Socket.io architecture/configuration to connect to the closest server when available

Tags: amazon-web-services, websocket, socket.io, socket.io-client, aws-global-accelerator

We have Global Accelerator setup in Amazon to route requests to the closest host from some multiple nodes.

How does socket.io play out in this case? If let's say a user connected, and the socket client is connected to host A, but then host B which is closer, becomes available, is there some way for the socket requests to be routed through this closest server?

The typical scenario would be that if for some reason host B is overloaded and the Accelerator just routes the socket client to use host A at the time, but now the user is stuck on the distant server until he refreshes.

Thanks